# Xamarin.Forms Null Ref Exception only when using Xamarin Live Preview

Tags: c#, android

So this might not be an actual problem with my code but something incorrect with the Xamarin Live Preview app. I have a forms project that is really small overall, most of the hard working code is actually a .Net standard library, that I am supplying as a Nuget package. My core class has an event that will fire when everything is ready to go inside the class. I originally thought that null reference was coming from the creation of my class however, I have found the 1 line that makes a difference. Comment out the event subscription and everything works, also this application works just fine inside an emulator or as a Win10 app.

Looking at all the code you might think well my `SnappleApi` object is the null reference, but in all my debugging it always has a value. The other main argument against this, is that emulators / local builds run just fine.

Visual Studio doesn't see any errors, it never hits anything past the event subscription. The live preview app shows, "Visualization Error: Null Reference Exception".

My startup code from the Forms project:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            //Starts this bad boy up
            InitializeComponent();

            //Sets the seconds remaining equal to the initial auto refresh period
            SecondsRemaining = AutoRefreshInterval;


            //Builds the api that is used for calling upon the snapple facts
            SnappleApi = new SnappleEngie();
            //Setups the trigger that is fired when the facts are available for usage
            SnappleApi.OnFactsLoaded += FactsAvailable;
        }
```

What that event code looks like:

```
private void FactsAvailable(object sender, bool isReload)
        {
            UpdateFact();

            if (SnappleApi.HasFacts)
            {
                //Start auto fact ticker
                AutoFactTimer = new Timer(AutoFactTick, null, 0, (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds); 
            }
        }
```

Lastly what that UpdateFact code looks like:

```
private void UpdateFact()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (SnappleApi.HasFacts)
                {
                    FactText.Text = GetNewRandomFact().ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    FactText.Text = "There was an error loading facts from the Snapple Servers.";
                }
            }));
        }
```